# Using a router.php script on PHP 7.2 Development Server to handle .htaccess mod rewrites

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My website runs perfectly when deployed to an Apache server.  It relies on this `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /c/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now I try to do some testing using the `PHP 7.2.2 Development Server` on localhost, which I understand does not make use of the `.htaccess` file because it doesn't rely on Apache.

I learned that it is possible to create a `router.php` script in the site root and then launch the local development server like this:

```
php -S localhost:8080 router.php
```

The `router.php` script is supposed to handle all the routing that the `.htaccess` file would normally handle on the Apache server.  I tried using a sample `router.php` script found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27381520/php-built-in-server-and-htaccess-mod-rewrites), but it doesn't work correctly for my setup.  I think the problem is that my `.htaccess` file utilizes `RewriteBase /c/` to provide a new base URL for the rewrite, but the `router.php` script does not have a similar base URL.  The problem that occurs with the given `router.php` script is that it is trying to rewrite all URLs, not just the ones in the new base URL of `/c/`.

My question is:  How should I prepare the `router.php` file in order to handle my specific `.htaccess` file noted above?

Comment: The question you link has some pretty thorough explanations and you don't explain what exactly isn't appropriate for you. Apache is a full-fledged HTTP server and PHP builtin server is a simple developer tool: you can't mimic 100% of the functionality of the former with the latter.

Comment: Thanks Alvaro.  I edited the question to show the specific problem I am experiencing with the `router.php` script.

Comment: It seems you're having a problem (rather than miss a feature). I'm not fully sure of what your problem is but perhaps you're missing the `-t` option ([reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php)). See also the [dots issue](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61286).